# vscode with jupyter with archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I am trying to install and use vscode with jupyter extension for coding with python on my archlinux OS. but it does not found any kernel interpreter

I installed both jupyter and python extension in vscode and tried many staff suggested on the internet, as

""enable-proposed-api": ["ms-toolsai.jupyter"]" in the argv.json

and "create environment"

 the result is always the same, jupyter file is corrected opened
but when i tried to select kernel, vscode keep searching.

 can someone sugggest me something?

Thanks in advances, cheers!